# BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration: The element [step2] is unreachable

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I had spring batch job similar to this one:

```xml
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        ...
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2">
        ...
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

and when tried to execute the job I got

```
BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The element [step2] is unreachable
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that there is missing `next` attribute in step1:

```xml
<batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
```